# Azure services: SFTP .xlsb multi tabs file loading, ETL and sending to Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

We need to load a file with `.xlsb` file extension from sftp, extract all rows from the file and certain columns, then send the extracted data to Function app.

The `*.xlsb` file contains two tabs, where all data is required for processing.

Qustions:

What Azure service can be used for this process of data loading, ETL and sending?

Answer (score 0):

> Qustions:
>
> What Azure service can be used for this process of data loading, ETL
>   and sending?

My idea is consists of two parts:

1.Use Azure Data Factory to transfer data from [SFTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp) source to [Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) sink with Copy Activity.

2.Use [Blob Storage Azure Function Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) to monitor any data into your blob storage account to trigger the function.

Comment: Does Azure Data Factory support xlsx file extension? The file will be uploaded to FTP once a week. How does Data Factory get notified and called?